# UINavigationBar.appearance().shadowImage = UIImage() in swift 4

Tags: swift4, xcode9, xcode9-beta, xcode9beta6

How can I implement this code in swift 4 or xcode 9?

```
// Remove hairline between navigation bar and anything below such as search bar
UINavigationBar.appearance().shadowImage = UIImage()
```

I want to remove navBar underline.

Comment: https://ibb.co/kokAok      check this image this code is not working for me.

Comment: [link](https://ibb.co/kokAok) check this image this code is not Working for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check :

```
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.shadowImage = UIImage()
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't worry copy pasting will work.

```
// Remove Bottom Shadow
UINavigationBar.appearance().shadowImage = UIImage()
UINavigationBar.appearance().setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), for: .default)
```